# Add product custom field(s) dynamically when Adding products on WooCommerce manual orders

Tags: woocommerce, settings, product, custom-fields, orders

I want to be able to add extra product options to a product, when adding products to a new manually added order from the backend (as admin).
Now if go to WooCommerce -> Orders -> Add New
Then in Order details form, click button "Add product(s)"
Then a "popup" with title: "Add products" is displayed.
Then I search for product to be added, and add a product into the select field.
Then I can continue to add more products.
The above is the default behaviour.

What I would like is when I seach for and select a product to be added (in the product select field), I would like to dynamically create extra product option field(s) dynamically - depending on which product is selected - and display those extra fields below the newly added product.

When the customer laiter view this order and related products on the frontend, or admin laiter view order and related products from backend - then I want the dynamically added product option fields to be visible (with label and value).

Note that the custom product option field(s) added dynamically here where admin manually add order in the backend, is not part of any fields for the actual product created in WooCommerce.

I would also like to add the code for this using a child theme (if possible).
I have tried to search for example on how to do this, but could not find anything.

Here is an image on where the dynamically added product option field(s) could be placed, where the order is manualy added in the backend (wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order)
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in a simple way that can be handled here on Stack Overflow without providing any related code and very poor details.

But you can add custom fields if you edit the product once added as follows:

[image]

Then when editing:

[image]

Click on "Add meta" button as many times you need. Each time, 2 input fields are displayed (one for the meta key and the other for the meta value):

[image]

**Note:** Meta keys starting with `_` will be only displayed on admin orders otherwise they will be displayed everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Could someone describe how I can insert custom javascript into the Add products form where admin manually add WooCommerce order in the backend?
And how can I handle the saving of the dynamically added input fields from the same form - in the backend?
I get the feeling that I have to write a plugin to handle this.
Information on the backend hooks needed to handle this, would be great.

Comment: It is the same question as in thread start. But since you said (at least indirectly) using child template to implement this was not possible, I was trying to find an answer on how to do it - but using a plugin instead. How can this break any rule?
I'm still looking for an answer on how to implement the same thing - but using a plugin. All I really need now is what I asked for in my previous comment.